# Which is has higher performance? Nvidia proprietary or Nouveau open source?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, graphics, nvidia

System: Manjaro 0.8.5.2 x64

Core 2 Duo P8700 @ 2.53Ghz

Nvidia GT 240M

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Source Engine games mostly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gaming: `nvidia` closed-source drivers outperform `nouveau` drivers. Here's a comparison between `nvidia` and `nouveau` on several nVidia GPUs, including the desktop version of your GPU:

[Nouveau vs. NVIDIA Linux Comparison](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nouveau_april_2013&num=1)